# iOS: Core Data Lag…?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm building a budget app and running into some problems with core data. I have a table structure, where there are main categories and sub categories. Each one has a name, and only one name is valid per combination. (i.e. I can have a subcategory insurance in several main categories, however not twice insurance in one main category).
So I can add, remove and rename main categories and subcategories without problems. However, when I rename a main category and open it up again to see its subcategories (this is in a navigation controller, you select a main category and in the next view you see the subcategories), none are visible for a while. After some seconds and a "reload" via reopening the subcategory they will be visible again.

I'm using a FetchedResultsController. Any idea where I'm missing something? Do I need to reload somewhere something? But I thought I don't have to reload the table while using FetchedResultsController?

These are the relevant code sections:

```
#pragma mark Initializer and view setup
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SpendingCategory"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES]];
    [self.mainCategory.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongsToMainCategory.name = %@", self.mainCategory.name];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                       managedObjectContext:self.mainCategory.managedObjectContext
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                  cacheName:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Edit/Done button
    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(editTable:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:editButton];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.sumTitleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSLocalizedString(@"Budget/Month", nil), @":"];
    self.categorySumTitleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.mainCategory.name, @":"];

    [self refreshIcon];
    self.iconButton.hidden = YES;
    self.iconImage.hidden = NO;

    self.mainCategoryNameTextField.text = self.mainCategory.name;
    self.mainCategoryNameTextField.delegate = self;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.sumLabel.text = [[DatabaseFetches budgetPerMonthForManagedObjectContext:self.mainCategory.managedObjectContext] getLocalizedCurrencyString];
    self.categorySumLabel.text = [[self.mainCategory getMonthlyCostsOfAllSpendingCategories] getLocalizedCurrencyString];
    [self refreshIcon];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Well you have posted your code for `setupFetchedResultsController`, but not shown where it is called from.

Comment: - (void)setMainCategory:(MainCategory *)mainCategory
{
    //TODO
    _mainCategory = mainCategory;
    self.title = mainCategory.name;
    [self setupFetchedResultsController];

}

Answer (score 0):

If your UI is not updating, it could be because the data is still cached. Maybe your detail view controller was not deallocated correctly.

There is no harm in simply reloading the table view before displaying:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated:
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

However, your table view should be brand new, so this is supposed to happen automatically. Check your view hierarchy logic.